# Testing BaseActivity

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-testing, robolectric, dagger

I have a BaseActivity, which has Dagger behavior inside:

```
abstract class BaseActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity(), HasSupportFragmentInjector {  
@Inject
lateinit var fragmentDispatchingAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment>

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
    AndroidInjection.inject(this)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)
 /**
 * Method that gets called after the [onCreate] method
 */
public override fun onPostCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState)
    applyDebugOverlay(this)
}

override fun supportFragmentInjector() = fragmentDispatchingAndroidInjector
}
```

Now I want to test, that applyDebugOverlay(this) is calling. For this, I use Robolectric in my AbstractActivityTest

```
   @Test
fun testDebugOverlayIsShown() {
    underTest.onPostCreate(Bundle())
    val buildTimeStamp = underTest.inc_debugOverlay_tv_date.text

    assert(buildTimeStamp.isNotEmpty())
}
```

But I get "No injector factory bound for Class" error, and it is not possible to bind BaseActivity with @ContributesAndroidInjector in my ActivityBuilder Class (would get another error).

Comment: FYI you don't need to implement `HasSupportFragmentInjector` manually since you inherit from `DaggerAppCompatActivity`